# Word for finding/looking out something in dark?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a specific word for your effort when you can't find something because of no light around. Please help?

Comment: By 'There is a specific word for your effort when you can't find something because of no light around.' do you really mean 'Is there a specific word for your effort when you can't find something because there is no light to see by?'? 'Fumbling around in the dark' is a reasonably common **expression**.

Comment: "Groping in the dark" is one more related expression ..

Comment: @Monzoor yes, _groping in the dark_. You stole my words :)

Comment: I just checked 'grope' and it sounds perfect in my case. Thank you @monzoor.

Comment: Well yes! Feels like I won the buzzer round.

Answer (score 5):

***Grope*** (verb) — [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grope)

> 1. Search blindly or uncertainly by feeling with the hands
>
> *"she groped for her spectacles"*
> *"He kneeled down, looking under the seat, and he groped blindly for the pen, stretching to get it."*

But be careful using it, because it has another definition.

> 2. *(informal)* Fondle (someone) for sexual pleasure roughly or clumsily, or without the person's consent

Comment: There is also *fumble*, which is perhaps a little safer.

Comment: As testified by the number of medieval streets known for prostitution in British towns and cities, called Gropecunt Lane (which were mostly changed to something else in a later, more decorous, age). This is the one in Oxford, known as Gropecunt Lane from 1205, now known as Magpie Lane. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/Magpie_lane.jpg/200px-Magpie_lane.jpg